# Can ServiceStack use binary serializers for non-HTTP clients, e.g. Google Protocol Buffers?

Tags: servicestack

As a followup to [Does ServiceStack support binary responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245616/does-servicestack-support-binary-responses), I'm wondering whether there are injection points built (or planned) to use binary serializers such as Mark Gravell's [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for efficiency between non-HTTP clients. In fact, it might not be long before protocol buffers work in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, ServiceStack has a custom pluggable format API where its own built-in [CSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-CSV-Format) and [HTML Report Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/HTML5ReportFormat) are both registered using it. The tutorial of Nortwind Database's [custom v-card media type](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm) shows how to register your own format/media type using this API.

Support for protobuf-net is planned for the near future. There was someone on the [ServiceStack Group](http://groups.google.com/group/servicestack) looking at exploring adding support for it. In any case, I plan to be catching up with protobuf-net's author soon so I'll find out the best way of how to add support for it then.