# Can the ServiceStack config setting "WebHostPhysicalPath" be used for relative paths?

Tags: servicestack

Hello ServiceStack aficionados!

I would like to host static XML files through the ServiceStack service; however, I can't seem to get the configuration right and only receive 404 errors.  Feels like I tried all sorts of path/url combinations.

Can the WebHostPhysicalPath be defined as a relative path?  Is there another setting that must be enabled?  I was concerned that maybe the XML extension is conflicting with the format conversion stuff.

Also, can I host Razor cshtml files this way too?

Any comments on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744093/servicestack-serving-static-files-from-a-directory-when-present)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a static file from a service like so:

```
[Route("/myFile/")]
public class GetMyFile
{
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public HttpResult Any(GetMyFile request)
    {
        return new HttpResult(new FileInfo("~/myfile.xml"), asAttachment:true) { ContentType = "text/xml" };
    }
}
```

As for razor: http://razor.servicestack.net/

Comment: FYI Adding 'xml' isn't needed as its [already pre-configured](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/EndpointHostConfig.cs#L87).

Comment: I thought so, I just couldn't remember. Since you're here, thanks for the only framework keeping me on .NET.

Comment: Thx, SS is keeping me on .NET as well - not sure if that's a good thing yet :)

Comment: I didn't want the files to be per-Service, so in the end I went with this linked approach, but haven't gotten to hosting my own razor just yet.  SS is awesome on .net, @mythz please stick with it! [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744093/servicestack-serving-static-files-from-a-directory-when-present) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744093/servicestack-serving-static-files-from-a-directory-when-present

Comment: Reflected on this a bit more and added your solution (@EricW.) to give it a whirl too - other than digging to find the namespace for HttpResult (servicestack.common.web for others on pre-4.0) and removing the ~, it worked cleanly and will explore this further.  Thanks!