# How can you disable jsv formatters for some request in a response filter?

Tags: servicestack

I have a servicestack server that uses a response filter to add data validation messages to our service.  My Put/Post handlers return a HttpResult object with Response set to our validation object.  The response filter then decomposes this object into a raw html string that it sets the Response object to.  In order to get this to work I had to create a String.md file in "views" along with a blank html template file.  The problem I am now seeing is when our custom html response contains a comma "," the jsv fromater tries to serialize the string and throws an exception:

```
   at System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvTypeSerializer.EatMapKey(String value, Int32& i)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeDictionary`1.ParseStringDictionary(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.Jsv.JsvReader`1.Parse(String value)
   at ServiceStack.Text.TypeSerializer.DeserializeFromString[T](String value)
   at ServiceStack.Html.ViewDataDictionary.PopulateModelState()
   at ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper.Init(IViewEngine viewEngine, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ServiceStack.Html.HtmlHelper.Init(MarkdownPage markdownPage, Dictionary`2 scopeArgs, Boolean renderHtml, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at ServiceStack.Markdown.MarkdownViewBase.Init(IAppHost appHost, MarkdownPage markdownPage, Dictionary`2 scopeArgs, Object model, Boolean renderHtml)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.Markdown.MarkdownPage.Write(TextWriter textWriter, PageContext pageContext)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.Markdown.TemplateExtensions.RenderToString(MarkdownPage markdownPage, Dictionary`2 scopeArgs, Boolean renderHtml)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.MarkdownFormat.RenderDynamicPage(MarkdownPage markdownPage, Dictionary`2 scopeArgs, Boolean renderHtml, Boolean renderTemplate)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.MarkdownFormat.RenderDynamicPage(MarkdownPage markdownPage, String pageName, Object model, Boolean renderHtml, Boolean renderTemplate)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.MarkdownFormat.ProcessMarkdownPage(IHttpRequest httpReq, MarkdownPage markdownPage, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.MarkdownFormat.<Register>b__1(IRequestContext requestContext, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SerializeToStream>b__0(StreamSerializerResolverDelegate x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Formats.HtmlFormat.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object dto, IHttpResponse httpRes)
   at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResponseFilter.SerializeToStream(IRequestContext requestContext, Object response, Stream responseStream) in i:\GitHub\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\Web\HttpResponseFilter.cs:line 152
   at ServiceStack.Common.Web.HttpResult.WriteTo(Stream responseStream) in i:\GitHub\ServiceStack\src\ServiceStack.Common\Web\HttpResult.cs:line 219
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToOutputStream(IHttpResponse response, Object result, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
   at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions.WriteToResponse(IHttpResponse response, Object result, ResponseSerializerDelegate defaultAction, IRequestContext serializerCtx, Byte[] bodyPrefix, Byte[] bodySuffix)
```

My question is how can i turn jsv off for these responses?  Or is there a better way to return raw html?  I cannot have my request handlers return a string since I need to control the response code and headers returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return a HTML string inside a HttpResult, e.g:

```
return new HttpResult("<html>...</html>", ContentType.Html);
```

For referemce ServiceStack's HTML Story can be found at:

[Is it possible to serve HTML pages with ServiceStack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199493/is-it-possible-to-serve-html-pages-with-servicestack/8200056#8200056)

In addition to Markdown, we've added new MVC Razor Support you can see examples of at in:

- [Razor Rockstars - with Razor views embedded in stand-alone self-host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RazorRockstars/RazorRockstars.Console)
- [Inside ASP.NET host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.RazorHostTests)