# using servicestack to return xml files unchanged via REST

Tags: xml, servicestack

Hi I wanted to know if anyone has modified the restfiles example in servicestack,
so that it can return unchanged xml files from the filesystem?

In other words, act as a webserver (IIS, cassini or apache etc.) but with REST mapping that comes with servicestack.

At the moment the response is preformated and i cant see how to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to show my solution to my original question in case others are looking to modify the restfiles example´s behaviour. the mod allows you to return xml or other filetypes to the browser without changing the content of the file:

```
public override object OnGet(Files request)
{
    var targetFile = GetAndValidateExistingPath(request);
    var isDirectory = Directory.Exists(targetFile.FullName);
    var hasParameters = this.RequestContext.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Contains("?") ? true : false;

    if (!isDirectory && request.ForDownload)
        return new HttpResult(targetFile, asAttachment:true);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFile.Name) || hasParameters)
    {
        var response = isDirectory
            ? new FilesResponse { Directory = GetFolderResult(targetFile.FullName) }
            : new FilesResponse { File = GetFileResult(targetFile) };
        return response;
    }
    return new HttpResult(targetFile);
}
```

So basically if the incomming request is empty or has parameters then we return a filesresponse otherwise we return an HttpResult directly displaying the files content.
I hope this is useful to somebody.

Mythz:  if there is something wrong in the code.. let us know. I tried to convert the example to .Net 4.0 but somewhere it breaks and the ajax file content viewing and listing part in /#!files  doesnt show up.  (perhaps i lost something in web.config during vs2010 conversion). Will you be releasing 4.0 compatible versions of the examples in the near future? ... Thanks again for the great work

Answer (score 1):

The RestFiles example already shows how to [return physical files from the filesystem](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.ServiceInterface/FilesService.cs#L30):

```
return new HttpResult(targetFile, asAttachment:true);
```

This shows another example of using a custom HttpResult to return a downloaded file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843621/85785