# Download file (html content) with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I'm using [Service Stack](http://www.servicestack.net/) for a simple web application.

In this app i need to "export" some content to Excel.. So this is the approach I took:

1. I get the HTML content of a table with jQuery a get the HTML content
   of a table, and send to the service.
2. The Service write the content to a file (with some CSS)
3. Using the same service, but with a `GET` method, I read the file and
   make the download with `ContentType:"application/vnd.ms-excel"`

I used this approach without Service Stack in other times, and worked well.. The `XLS` file had the right content and some colors.

Now, when I get the file using `GET` method (i.e., visiting the url with the browser), the file contents are bad.

ServiceStack let download with some formats: html, csv, jsv, json, xml.

The html format shows up a default report page, the only format that works a little is jsv.

My question is: how can I download the file like plain html file?

Some code:

```
public class ExcelService : RestServiceBase<Excel>
{   
    public override object OnGet (Excel request)
    {
        string file = request.nombre;
        //Response.Clear();
        HttpResult res = new HttpResult();
        res.Headers[HttpHeaders.ContentType] = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        res.Headers[HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition] = "attachment; filename="+file+".xls";
        string archivo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("tmp/"+file+".html");
        res.Response = archivo;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HttpResult Constructor in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) as an overload that supports file downloads, e.g:

```
return new HttpResult(new FileInfo("tmp/"+file+".html"), 
    asAttachment: true, 
    contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Which will set the `ContentDisposition` HTTP headers required for file downloading.

#### Creating your own Http Result

For more fine-grained control of the HttpOutput you can also create your own Result class. Here is an example of downloading an Excel spreadsheet taken from the [customized responses in ServiceStack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245616/does-servicestack-support-binary-responses/9843621#9843621):

```
public class ExcelFileResult : IHasOptions, IStreamWriterAsync
{
    private readonly Stream _responseStream;
    public IDictionary<string, string> Options { get; private set; }

    public ExcelFileResult(Stream responseStream)
    {
        _responseStream = responseStream;

        Options = new Dictionary<string, string> {
             {"Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"},
             {"Content-Disposition", ""attachment; filename=\"report.xls\";"}
         };
    }

    public async Task WriteToAsync(Stream responseStream, CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        if (_responseStream == null) 
            return;

        await _responseStream.CopyToAsync(responseStream, token);
        await responseStream.FlushAsync(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good example, worked for me. Worth noting that this class above is the reponse class which is returned by the service action.

Comment: How should you update this answer with IStreamWriterAsync?

Comment: @mythz thank you.In a web environment (.NET Framework 4.6) I had to replace "CopyToAsync" with "WriteToAsync". Otherwise, the content is a 0 length file (even if Unit Testing with "CopyToAsync" returns a stream with expected length).

Comment: @labilbe Strange, maybe your `_responseStream` Position isn't set to `0`?

Comment: @mythz kudos!! That was the reason. I'm impressed!